# How to get Windows credential for NTLM / Kerberos from C++ for libcurl?

Tags: c++, windows, libcurl

I have a fairly basic question for using libcurl, which I could not find an answer from googling/stackoverflow.

I would like to use libcurl to authenticate user to a remote Windows site.  To do that, I need to pass in the Windows credentials (domain/user/password) to libcurl.  How to I retrieve the current login user's credential from Visual C++ for this purpose?  Goal is not to have to prompt user again for their Windows credentials.

Comment: To get the current user's name and domain you can use [GetUserNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [LookupAccountName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But retrieving a password without prompting user as far as I now is impossible in legal way , but you can decrypt passwords that are stored on SAM file ;)

Comment: Thanks Apokal.  So prompt be it. It would have been much easier if do it in C#, using the DefaultCredential, which you can use as is to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't if you could this was a security breach 
Trojans could steal  user's credential.

usually for authentication systems only save the a hash(md5/sha1) of the password , not the password itself so even if one have an accesses to that hash he cant steal the password. as he need the password not the hash.
i don't know about windows but i believe they do the same.